# Is there a way to handle different, changing class_names when extracting from a website in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping data from a website, and taking a specific piece of information. This could exist under the class 'text-error' or 'text-success.' It changes depending on if the value is positive or negative. So, I tried

```
   success = soup.find('span', class_='text-success')
```

for one class but am not sure how to handle if it's the 'text-error' class. How can I return only the existing value? I'm also running this in a loop to continually check the values.

Comment: So do you want to search for `class_='text-success'` or `class_='text-error'` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I want to search for both, because only one exists at a time in the space I'm looking for, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can be one or the other use CSS OR syntax to specify a match on whichever class is present in a list:

```
success = soup.select_one('.text-error, .text-success')
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there are more elegant solutions, I used `try` on each class name. i.e.

```
try:
   success = soup.find('span', class_='text-success')
    ...
except:
    ...
try:
   success = soup.find('span', class_='text-success')
    ...
except:
    ...
```

And it worked.